MySQL - ETL - Problema al hacer CAST en un datetime a date
Estoy en una base orige MySQL y estoy haciendo unos ETL en Pentaho hacia una tabla SQLServer, en la tabla origen manejo un datetime, pero por un requerimiento especifico en la tabla destino debo almacenar date. Sin embargo me he topado con un problema cuando encuentro un datetime con fecha/hora 2023-01-01 00:00:00, ya que al destino llega como 2022-12-31, revisando los QRYs de extraccion estos se generan de forma correcta
SELECT
    A.FECHA,
    CAST(A.FECHA AS DATE) CAST_FECHA
FROM TABLA A

y devuelve:
|fecha              |CAST_FECHA    |
|-------------------|--------------|
|2023-01-01 00:00:00|2023-01-01    |

Pero el destino recibe>
|fecha     |
|----------|
|2022-12-31|

El problema es que este es un campo que se requiere para actualizar la tabla destino en el ETL, y este registro va quedando y duplicandose cada vez que se ejecuta el ETL.
¿Que puede estar generando esta diferencia? ¿Hay alguna forma de solventarlo?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Suena a que es un error en cómo pasas los datos, es decir, puede que directamente ese dato no lo recibe y esa fecha sea el valor por defecto de la columna en SQL Server

A mi me parece un problema relacionado con zonas horarias. Yo que tú haría la prueba de crear una tabla que tenga hora y pasar a SQL Server el dato con la hora, para ver si la diferencia con la que está pasando son 24 horas o no. Mi hipótesis es que no son 24 horas, sino algún período menor. Luego puedes irte por analizar configuraciones hasta ajustar lo necesario o simplemente sumar una X cantidad de horas a la columna de orígen.
